# Most optimized way of scanning a very large directory in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to scan a drive of 80 GB, which has multiple directories. Each directory contains some files with extension of .txt, I want to copy these files to other directory? I intend to do this in least possible time, how do I achieve this in Python.

I am able to do this by this way:

```
import os

DIRS = [dirs for dirs in os.listdir()]

for var in DIRS:
    if var.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy('C:\\users\\testfolder', var)
```

Any better & optimized way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think that that the bottle neck in this is going to be the read/write time of the actual drive so I don;t think there is much room for improvement modifying the code

Comment: thank you @Nevado ! I want to check whether we can reduce the read write time using (map, filter & chain ) or subprocess.call() or anyother approach.

Comment: Since were talking about alot of I/O time I think threads could benefit you here

Comment: Some more questions that might be relevant: Does the HDD have a capacity of 80 GB, or do you actually have 80 GB of data to chew trough? How many files are there? How much of those (both in number of tiles and total file size) are the files you want to copy? And is it a HDD or a SSD? Depending on the answers to those question, different things might work.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k, there's a typo. I have corrected it. Going further, drive is fragmented HDD of 80GB. Number of Total subdirectories is 23 & is bound to increase .

Answer (score 1):

If you have a deeper folder structure `os.walk` or `os.scandir` are made for the purpose of efficiently walk a folderstructure. With `os.listdir` you get a list, which if they are large, are considerable slower than the generators you get from for example `os.scandir`.

As mentioned in the comments it's unlikely that you can speed up write operations on a single hdd, however read operations could benefit from multiple processes.